# How to consume in-process WCF services from unmanaged C++

Tags: c#, c++, wcf

I have some WCF services running over HTTP and a C++ client using gSOAP to consume them. This works, but we are considering running the service host in the same process as the client, to create a fully local stack.

What is the best way to allow the C++ client to consume these services? Do we still need to use HTTP binding? Or will something like named pipes or [NullTransport](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/NullTransportForWCF.aspx) work? Preferably something that will work with gSOAP or something that we can replace gSOAP with.

Answer (score 0):

if both are in the same process then have them "talk" to each other via direct means. i.e. accessing objects directly.  otherwise going over a comms layer is extremely expensive.  the same can be said for accessing files on your hard drive via a network share when really going file say c:\foo\something.txt is more productive.

c++ allows you to construct CLR types that are both native code but also CLR-aware.  using this technique allows your c++.NET type so to speak from .NET proper.  your .NET types will have no idea that they are invoking c++ or vice versa.

have a look in your c++ compiler settings for CLR